# goocanvasmm text item set anchor

Tags: gtk, gtkmm

I want to set the text anchor for a goocanvasmm text item. But I can't get the examples to run

```
Goocanvas::Text::create("Any Text", 0, 0, -1, Goocanvas::ANCHOR_NORTH);
```

error: 'ANCHOR_NORTH' is not a member of 'Goocanvas'

```
Goocanvas::Text::create("Any Text", 0, 0, -1, Goocanvas::ANCHOR_N);
```

error: 'ANCHOR_N' is not a member of 'Goocanvas'

I have no idea in which namespace or subclass this item is located. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition of the enumerator is as follows:

```
enum    Goocanvas::AnchorType {

  Goocanvas::ANCHOR_CENTER,

  Goocanvas::ANCHOR_NORTH,

  Goocanvas::ANCHOR_NORTH_WEST,

  Goocanvas::ANCHOR_NORTH_EAST,

  Goocanvas::ANCHOR_SOUTH,

  Goocanvas::ANCHOR_SOUTH_WEST,

  Goocanvas::ANCHOR_SOUTH_EAST,

  Goocanvas::ANCHOR_WEST,

  Goocanvas::ANCHOR_EAST,

  Goocanvas::ANCHOR_N = ANCHOR_NORTH,

  Goocanvas::ANCHOR_NW = ANCHOR_NORTH_WEST,

  Goocanvas::ANCHOR_NE = ANCHOR_NORTH_EAST,

  Goocanvas::ANCHOR_S = ANCHOR_SOUTH,

  Goocanvas::ANCHOR_SW = ANCHOR_SOUTH_WEST,

  Goocanvas::ANCHOR_SE = ANCHOR_SOUTH_EAST,

  Goocanvas::ANCHOR_W = ANCHOR_WEST,

  Goocanvas::ANCHOR_E = ANCHOR_EAST

}
```

So your code *should* work unless you did some namespace foo (i.e. `use blurb`). Try to use the C defines (i.e. `ANCHOR_SOUTH_WEST` - no namespace) directly.

Comment: It was a configuration bug in the Makefile. I did not use gtkmm-3.0  in pkg-config command.